# Gauss-Weingarten relations on an arbitrary Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I'm trying to derive the Gauss-Weingarten relations on a hypersurface immersed on an arbitrary Riemannian manifold (see page $468$ of [this paper](https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_152768/component/file_152767/content) for the context):

> $\begin{cases}
> \frac{\partial^2 F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_ix_j} - \Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_k} + \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial F^{\rho}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial F^{\sigma}}{\partial x_j} = -h_{ij} \nu^{\alpha}\\
> \frac{\partial \nu^{\alpha}}{\partial x_j} + \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial F^{\rho}}{\partial x_j} \nu^{\sigma} = h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_m}
> \end{cases}$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Firstly, I will prove the first equation. By one hand, I used the local formula for covariant derivative of the vector field $\overline{\nabla}_j F$ along $i$-parameter curves (see pages $122$ and $123$ of Barrett O'Neill - Semi-Riemannian Geometry with Applications to General Relativity for details):

$\begin{align*}
\overline{\nabla}_i \overline{\nabla}_j F &= \sum_\limits{\alpha=1}^n \left\{ \frac{\partial^2 F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} + \sum_\limits{\rho,\sigma} \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial F^{\rho}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial F^{\sigma}}{\partial x_j} \right\} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}}
\end{align*}$

By the other hand,

$\begin{align*}
\overline{\nabla}_i \overline{\nabla}_j F &= \sum_\limits{\alpha=0}^n \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}}\\
&= \sum_\limits{k=1}^n \Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} - h_{ij} \nu
\end{align*}$

Combining these two observations,

$$\frac{\partial^2 F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_ix_j} - \Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_k} + \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial F^{\rho}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial F^{\sigma}}{\partial x_j} = -h_{ij} \nu,$$

which is different from the original equation by the term $-h_{ij} \nu$. I would like to know where I'm missing.

I will prove the second equation. By one hand, I used the local formula for covariant derivative of the vector field $\nu$ along $j$-parameter curves:

$\begin{align*}
\overline{\nabla}_j \nu &= \sum_\limits{\alpha=0}^n \left\{ \frac{\nu^{\alpha}}{\partial x_j} + \sum_\limits{\rho,\sigma} \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial F^{\rho}}{\partial x_j} \nu^{\sigma} \right\} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}}
\end{align*}$

By the other hand,

$\begin{align*}
\overline{\nabla}_j \nu &= h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_m}
\end{align*}$

I want to combine these two observations in order to obtain

$$\frac{\partial \nu^{\alpha}}{\partial x_j} + \overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{\partial F^{\rho}}{\partial x_j} \nu^{\sigma} = h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_m},$$

but I can't because I have a derivation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}}$ by one hand and a number $\frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_m}$ by the other hand. I would like to know what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a quick look to your good effort shows that sadly in the equation $\begin{align*}
\overline{\nabla}_j \nu &= h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial F^{\alpha}}{\partial x_m}
\end{align*}$ the indices are unbalanced (LHS and RHS must have the same set of free indices for a tensor equality to be viable).

Comment: There should be $\alpha$ in the two equations about the derivative of $\nu.$

Comment: Hello, George. Did you finish the work at last? I'm stuck in the same question. Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat, I didn't finish.

Comment: @George Thank you for replying me. These equations are frequently mentioned and employed in the literature on geometric flows, yet few people would like to verify them. As a beginner, I'd say it is really frustrating to see it happen.